# Android ListView in Fragment not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a listView inside of a Fragment of my MainActivity that is rendered by a custom ArrayAdapter. The problem is that the listview cannot scroll for some reason.

My XML MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#f1f1f1">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    design:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My XML Fragment:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:context=".Friends">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/newfriendbutton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:text="@string/new_friend"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/instruct"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newfriendbutton"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/friendListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="592dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should try fix your layout, `layout_height="592dp"` does not look right

Comment: No thats not the issue

Comment: You should really use weights, not fixed sizes, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the ListView is full? It will only let you scroll if you have more options in the View than what can fit with the given constraints. It might work best to use a RelativeLayout in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:context=".Friends">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newfriendbutton"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:text="@string/new_friend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/instruct"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newfriendbutton"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friendListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Indeed the list wasn't full.